# Javascript/ Easeljs Adding Dynamic Text

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm using HTML5 Canvas in Adobe Animate.
I'm trying to write a function that allows me to drop a text message anywhere on the stage.

Please see my code below.

```
function newtext(TextToDisplay, xposition, yposition, textcolor, textfont) 
{var textvar = new createjs.Text();
textvar.x = xposition;
textvar.y = yposition;
textvar.color = textcolor;
textvar.font = textfont;
textvar.text = TextToDisplay;
this.addChild(textvar);}
newtext("Hi there!",200,200,"#ff7799","50px Arial");
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can't find a viewer that includes EaselJS packages, so showing error messages here will not make much sense. Additionally, "Compiler Errors" is greyed out as a window option in Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas, so I can't see the errors there when I test my code.
If anyone can suggest a suitable viewer, that would be helpful as well.

I just wanted to add what I used to pull the code from, and this code works outside of the function.

```
var fl_TF = new createjs.Text();
var fl_TextToDisplay = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
fl_TF.x = 200;
fl_TF.y = 100;
fl_TF.color = "#ff7700";
fl_TF.font = "20px Arial";
fl_TF.text = fl_TextToDisplay;
this.addChild(fl_TF);
```

A commenter suggested the presence of "this" in the function might be the issue. It may be  part of the problem, as well as something else being wrong.

Comment: A deleted answer suggested that `this` is incorrect (would be global in this example). Another possible solution is updating the stage after adding the text.

Comment: Thanks, Lanny. Unfortunately, removing "this" and adding stage.update() after adding the text did not fix the issue. They were good suggestions, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it looks like the `addChild` is failing because the `newText()` method is called without a scope.

You *should* be receiving console logs showing that you "addChild is not a function".

You can not simply remove `this`. You have two simple options though:

1) The hacky often used to get around this issue is the "this/that" pattern:

```
var that = this;
function newText(your args) {
  // your other code
  that.addChild(fl_TF); // <-- Uses "that" which references the original scope
}
```

2) You can also just call the method in the correct scope:

```
newText.call(this, "Hi There", 200, 200, "#ff0000", "50px Arial");
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: FANTASTIC! Thank you so much! Option 2 worked a treat!

Comment: I wanted to add that this will work for variables with numeric values as well.
var C=5;
newtext.call(this, C, 200, 200, "#ff0000", "50px Arial");
will print a 5 at the desired location.